# Unfamiliar w/ Ring Notation

Tags: ring-theory, finite-rings

I'm used to seeing rings represented as sets, but in one of my homework problems, I am asked to:

> Find the number of zero-divisors of $R_{x^2-x}$.

Can somebody please explain what this notation actually means, as I've never seen it before? If the context of the question is required, previous questions have been about the subring $R = \{ax^2+bx+c \mid a \in 4\mathbb{Z}_8, b \in 2\mathbb{Z}_8, c \in \mathbb{Z}_8\}$ of $\mathbb{Z}_8[x]$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could it be the localization at that element?

Comment: Can you comment or rule out anything? Or perhaps point us to a copy of the page online? Does it come from a book or is it a typewritten assignment!

Comment: Seeing as $\Bbb Z_8$ is used for $\Bbb Z /\Bbb 8\Bbb Z$, I would suspect that $R_{x^2-x} = R/(x^2-x)$. In other words, the ring is $\Bbb Z_8/I$, where I is the ideal generated by the polynomial $x^2-x$.